# jQuery on-input change event update self

Tags: jquery

I am trying to format and update an input value using the jQuery on-input change event. The goal is to format the number with fixed decimal places (ie, currency).

Here is my code: (http://jsfiddle.net/xpvt214o/633563/)

My selector is the class `.format-currency` so I can use it on any input I want.

I can get the desired format (output to `console.log`), but I cannot get it to update the form's value using `$( this ).val()`. Any ideas how to accomplish this?

```js
$('.format-currency').on('input', function() {
  var $input = parseFloat($(this).val());
  if (isNaN($input)) {
    return false;
  }
  console.log('DEBUG — change in .format-currency — $input ⇒ ' + $input + '  — new val ⇒ ' + $input.toLocaleString('en-US', {
    style: 'decimal',
    minimumFractionDigits: 2,
    maximumFractionDigits: 2,
    useGrouping: false,
  }));
  $(this).val($input.toLocaleString('en-US', {
    style: 'decimal',
    minimumFractionDigits: 2,
    maximumFractionDigits: 2,
    useGrouping: false,
  }));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <input type='number' class='format-currency' min='0.00' max='9999.99' step='0.01' name='fee' />
</form>
```

Comment: The problem is that you're updating the value as soon as the user types anything, so they can't delete a character and replace it with something else.

Answer (score 0):

How about just parsing it to two decimal places? And update on `blur` event. You can use `parseFloat`. Somethiing like...

```
$('.format-currency').on('blur', function(){
    const v = $(this).val();
    if(isNaN(v) || v === "")//this line may need amending depending on validation
        return false;

    $(this).val(parseFloat(v).toFixed(2));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess this cannot be done since the input type is number and so the val() is stored as a float.  I guess I could change the type to text but then I would lose min, max and step... these were/should never be used as validators.